# Idea can't rename package named like ''integer' or 'Exception'

Tags: java, intellij-idea

As the topic, our project has a old package named as javaBase.Exception , we want to change the package name Excption to javaexception , when we select the package and  do the  'Rename' action, the IDEA suspented in Looking for useage step. 
[image: Rename the package]

How can I solve it?

Comment: What error do you see?  Your question could use some editing too.

Answer (score 0):

Refractoring can fail for all kinds of reasons but here are 2 that I have encountered:

1. There are errors in your project not necessarily related to the refractoring but will still cause problems.
2. Your IDE doesnt have enough memory to run the refractor and is just getting an out of memory error. You can lookup how to increase your IDE avaible memory online.

If the refractor doesn't work you can just do a search and replace in files for `javaBase.Exception` and replace it with `javaBase.javaexception`. In eclipse this is `ctrl+H` I am unsure of the keyboard shortcut in intelliJ.